# if and else have incompatible types

Tags: rust

I have an `if-else` block which returns an error in the else statement.

I understand why this code doesn't compile. I also understand one way it can be fixed. However, I do not think this results in good, maintainable code.

I suspect there is a better way, but I don't know what it is.

```
// fn someFunction() -> Result<something, something_else>

if condition_which_is_not_an_error {
    println!("This is ok");
    // maybe do some stuff
}
else {
    println!("something is wrong");
    Err(some_error)
}

if some_other_condition {
    println!("still ok");
    // do some more stuff
    Ok(some_good_thing_to_return)
}
else {
    println!("something else is wrong!");
    Err(some_error_probably)
}
```

It can be fixed with a rather obvious solution. But if we have `n` if-else statements, then we end up with deeply nested conditions, or a proliferation of difficult to maintain function calls to hide the depth of nesting. This is less readable than multiple blocks of short error-checking statements.

```
if condition_which_is_not_an_error {
    println!("This is ok");
    
    if some_other_condition {
        println!("still ok");
        // do some more stuff
        Ok(some_good_thing_to_return)
    }
    else {
        println!("something else is wrong!");
        Err(some_error_probably)
    }
}
else {
    println!("something is wrong");
    Err(some_error)
}
```

I also considered another possible alternative using the following:

```
let mut the_result: Result<something, something_else> = Ok(?);

if ... {

}
else {
    the_result = Err(?);
}

// ... same idea repeated, but only mutate the_result from
// Ok -> Err, not the other way around
```

These are sketches of ideas, not real code which compiles.

Answer (score 2):

What about simply (notice the `return`):

```rust
if condition_which_is_not_an_error {
    println!("This is ok");
    // maybe do some stuff
}
else {
    println!("something is wrong");
    return Err(some_error);
}

if some_other_condition {
    println!("still ok");
    // do some more stuff
    Ok(some_good_thing_to_return)
}
else {
    println!("something else is wrong!");
    Err(some_error_probably)
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize that adding `return` "makes it just work". Thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

This code is way way too general to provide anything but an opinionated answer but how about:

```
if !condition_which_is_not_an_error {
    return Err(condition_not_met);
}

// do some stuff

if !some_other_condition {
    return Err(some_error_probably);
}

// do rest of the stuff

Ok(result)

}
```

Comment: I didn't realize that adding `return` "makes it just work". Thanks for this